# Decimal Precision in Odoo dependent on Currency Type

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to modify how many decimals are shown on a purchase order line Unit Price field dependent on the currency_id?  For example, sometimes we purchase items in USD and need to have two decimal places on the Unit Price. In other cases, we purchase items in IDR (1 USD = 14635 IDR !) and do not want any decimals. Using decimal places with IDR can be confusing since there are already so many zeros.

[image: IDR price example]

Comment: I suggest you create another field dependent on this one and control the visibility based on some check on currency id, and the new field will have decimal precision that you will select.

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer mode.

Go to Accounting > settings > Currency.

Get to your currency form view.
Check the field **Rounding Factor** set it to 1 (Usually it will be 0.01/0.001 based on currency).

Remember, this change is all over the system.

For Unit Price, you could have 2 fields in view.. replacing the original. Based on currency you could show each(1. original attribute & 2. without decimals)

```
<xpath expr="//..../field[@name='price_unit']" position="replace">
    <field name="price_unit" digits="(16,0)"/>
</xpath>
```

This might help, if you don't want to have new fields and add complications. Or else, new field also will work as Yusuf suggested.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, but the "product_unit" field on order_line in the purchase.order record still shows the decimal based on the product. I think I need to add another computed field to the order_line to check the currency_id like Muhammad suggested.

price_unit = fields.Float(string='Unit Price', required=True, digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price'))

Comment: You are okay to have two fields showing same unit price(1 with decimal and another without) in line items? Doesn't seem like optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create new compute fields and to use those.

I wouldn't change the currency accuracy as someone else advised you because this has **A LOT** of side effects on your Odoo database and can result in some inconsistent numbers.